# HP Probook 4530s Maximum native resolution support

Tags: resolution

Is there possible that HP 4530s with "1GB AMD Radeon 6470 Graphics Card" can support resolution more then 1366 x 768?

Because I think on Intel HD card HP 4530s can only give max resolution of 1366x768.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you bought an upgrade, you are correct that 1366x768 is the maximum resolution.

http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-HP-ProBook-4530s-Notebook.56747.0.html (go about half way down to the "Display" section)

Comment: KCotreau , what you mean by upgrade? Is it not possible that the AMD Radeon Graphics card gives more resolution support?

Comment: What I meant, and go read that review (maybe the most detailed laptop review ever), it mentioned that some of those models came with a different, upgraded display/screen, and although they did not mention it, they put in a better video card to go along with that. Usually the way laptop makers describe resolution is by the display/screen you buy rather than the video card itself. I guess it is easier to understand for most people. The card you have is maxed out at 1366x768.

Comment: KCotreau, thanks I read the article and got the idea, sigh don't know what they are stick with 1366x768 resolution, I prefer bigger then this but v hard to find in low price laptops.

Comment: So you have not bought it yet?

Comment: I was going tomorrow to buy it but u saved my day thanks, I have mailed the dealer to find for me 1600x900 model of the machine, thanks mate

Comment: Glad I could help, and thank you for marking the answer.